# XML DocumentBuilder removes CDATA Section

Tags: java, xml, cdata

I have webapp on **weblogic** , which 

1.reads XML from database

2.parses it 

3.adds new section

Source XML has CDATA sections

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>     
    <script type="calcscript">
    <![CDATA[  some data ]]>
    </script>
```

When I parse xml

```
  DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document xml = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
```

It removes CDATA section!
After back converting to string

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
Result output = new StreamResult(sw);
Source input = new DOMSource(xml);
transformer.transform(input, output);
```

I get XML like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<script type="calcscript">
some data
</script>
```

Why does it remove CDATA sections ? may be **weblogic** includes old java libs which does not support CDATA section.

P.S. when I run app on tomcat server or java application everythingh works fine

Comment: I suggest the first thing you should do is to find out whether it's actually in the parsing or the formatting part. Look at all the nodes within the parsed document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the parsing process does not remove the CDATA information. Look at some debug info:

[image: Debug Variables]

Second: It is the transformation process that gets rid of those CDATA sections because this is simply not defined in the spec (look at the answer from Michael Kay [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384238/java-format-xml-using-transformer-with-cdata-part)).

You can however set some properties to the transformer that enables it to preserve those sections:

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS, "script");
```

Now you will have the CDATA section in the output.

Comment: You are right.... Thank you. After setting transformer property it parses XML with cdata section